# Flexible method parameters?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a class with the following method.

```
public cIPLink(int paramCaseNo, int paramIPID, string paramIPReference, int paramContactID)
    {            
        this.cLinkDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.cCaseNo = paramCaseNo;
        this.cIPID = paramIPID;
        this.cIPReference = paramIPReference;
        this.cContactID = paramContactID;

        string strConnect = BuildConnectionString();
        SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(strConnect);
        linkToDB.Open();

        string sqlStat = "INSERT INTO tblIPLinks (LinkID, LinkDate, CaseNo, IPID, ContactID, IPReference)" +
                         "VALUES (@LinkID, @LinkDate, @CaseNo, @IPID, @ContactID, @IPReference);";
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sqlStat, linkToDB);

        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@LinkID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@LinkDate", SqlDbType.Date);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CaseNo", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IPID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@ContactID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IPReference", SqlDbType.Text);

        this.cLinkID = NextLinkID();

        sqlCom.Parameters["@LinkID"].Value = this.cLinkID;
        sqlCom.Parameters["@LinkDate"].Value = this.cLinkDate;
        sqlCom.Parameters["@CaseNo"].Value = this.cCaseNo;
        sqlCom.Parameters["@IPID"].Value = this.cIPID;
        sqlCom.Parameters["@ContactID"].Value = this.cContactID;
        sqlCom.Parameters["@IPReference"].Value = this.cIPReference;

        sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

        linkToDB.Close();
    }
```

However I want to make this a little more flexible. Sometimes when the method is called I want to drop the field IPID, and sometimes I want to drop the field ContactID.  Now I thought about copying and pasting this code and having three overload methods; one with just IPID, one wth just ContactID and a third with both fields, but I'm sure there must be a neater way of doing what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Optional arguments?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: I think optional arguments in most cases are evil - google "optional argumens c# evil" (quote: The reason that optional parameters were introduced to C# 4 in the first place was to support COM interop.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using dotnet 4.0 and above, you can use optional parameters.

```
public cIPLink(int paramCaseNo, int paramIPID = -1, 
    string paramIPReference = null, int paramContactID = -1)
```

So, from that moment on you can invoke it as follows:

```
cIPLink( paramCaseNo );
cIPLink( paramCaseNo, paramContactID:5 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Make this method take nullable `int?` instead of plain `int`, change code to pay attention to `null` values in these, and add three single-line overloads forwarding the calls to the do-work private method.

```
private void cIPLinkImpl(int paramCaseNo, int? paramIPID, string paramIPReference, int? paramContactID) {
    // Your implementation goes here.
    // check paramIPID and paramContactID to null before using them here
}

public void cIPLink(int paramCaseNo, int paramIPID, string paramIPReference, int paramContactID) {
    cIPLinkImpl(paramCaseNo, paramIPID, paramIPReference, paramContactID);
}

public void cIPLink(int paramCaseNo, string paramIPReference, int paramContactID) {
    cIPLinkImpl(paramCaseNo, null, paramIPReference, paramContactID);
}

public void cIPLink(int paramCaseNo, int paramIPID, string paramIPReference) {
    cIPLinkImpl(paramCaseNo, paramIPID, paramIPReference, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With C# 4.0 you can use named and optional arguments. So if you have a method like this:

```
static int CalculateBMI(int weight, int height)
{
    return (weight * 703) / (height * height);
}
```

you can call it like this the normal way:

```
    Console.WriteLine(CalculateBMI(123, 64));
```

or like any of these:

```
    Console.WriteLine(CalculateBMI(weight: 123, height: 64));
    Console.WriteLine(CalculateBMI(height: 64, weight: 123));

    Console.WriteLine(CalculateBMI(123, height: 64));
```

Setting an initial value on the declaration makes them optional:

```
public int area(int height = 0, int width = 0)
{
    return height * width;
}
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use optional parameters if using C# 4.0

Answer (score 0):

you could use default parameters like

```
public cIPLink(int paramCaseNo, string paramIPReference, int paramIPID = -1, int paramContactID = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ideas would be move those parameters to class, something like:

```
public class QueryParameters 
{
     public int? CaseNo {get;set;} 
     public int? IPID {get;set;} 
     public string IPReference {get;set;}
     public int? ContactID {get;set;}
}
```

And then instead of passing many parameters as arguments, you would pass single parameter of type QueryParameters, and you would fill required properties of QueryParameters when passing to your method:

```
QueryParameters queryParameters = new QueryParameters();
queryParameters.IPReference = "blabla";

...

public cIPLink(QueryParameters queryParameters) 
{
    if (queryParameters.CaseNo.HasValue) {
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Overall, it is recommended way, not to have more that 4-5 method parameters, better refactor them to a separate class.

Comment: I am wondering if this is the recommended approach, even if i have around 30-40 methods like this (with 4-8 parameters). Should i create a "parameters" class per method?

Comment: if most of your methods have 4-8 params, then your doing too much in single method i think(for each test you'll need 4-8 params also), it may be that you are breaking single responsibility principle. If it is a large solution and only several methods have such parameter count, it may be better to group those parameters in classes, it does not only product easier maintainable code, but also easier readable - you don't need to have long method calls, as object creation you can have in separate line. Anyway, there's no strict rule, you need to decide for your self for each concrete case.

Comment: These parameters are being submitted into an HTTP request. As such, it does not break the SRP, since the HTTP request can send different data to the server, some of it is optional. For example, imagine a "Get Users" HTTP API call, where i can specify the user's name, email, and (optionally) a date range of some sort, etc. Would you consider this sort of API to break SRP?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set default values of the parameters to be null and then check and set them in your logic:

```
void method(int value = -1, string something = null) {
  if (value != -1) ... add parameter
  if (something != null) ... add parameter
}
```